# Get innerHtml of script-tag using JavaScript returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, undefined, innerhtml

I try to get the innerHtml of a script-tag using JavaScript.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
console.log(scripts.length);
console.log(scripts[0].innerHtml);
```

This script logs `2` and `undefined`, but why does it return undefined when there are 2 scripts found? I need to get the innerHtml of the script. Anny help would be appreciated :)

**Edit:**
After changing `innerHtml` to `innerHTML` it still throws an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined (line 34)
```

line 34 is this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"); //line 32
for (var i = 0, imax = scripts.length; i < imax; i++) { //line 33
var scriptstring = scripts[i].innerHTML; } // line 34
```

Btw, the script isn't an embedded .js file, it's hardcoded in the .html file

**Edit 2:** The whole .html file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        onmousemove = function test1() {
            window.alert('hello');
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

            for (var i = 0, imax = scripts.length; i < imax; i++) {
                var scriptstring = scripts[i].innerHTML;
                scriptstring = scriptstring.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""); //convert the innerHTML to one line, easier to match

                if (scriptstring.match(/.*(function) (test1).*/) != null) {
                    scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try debugging and check what was wrong with you Scripts[0].innerHTML

Comment: it's innerHTML, it's not innerHtml.

Comment: Could you also post the complete html file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
innerHtml
```

should be:

```
innerHTML
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be `.innerHTML`, not `.innerHtml`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `script` tag you're calling `innerHTML` on declares its source via the `src` attribute and not inside the element itself.

Comment: The script isn't an embedded .js file, it's hardcoded in the .html file

Answer (score 1):

because it is  `innerHTML` not `innerHtml`

Answer (score 0):

Please, rewrite this line
`for (var i = 0, imax = scripts.length; i < imax; i++)`
to
`for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++)`
because 
`var scriptstring = scripts[i].innerHTML;`
line run error at last index (first script deleted therefore `scripts.length` decremented and `imax` didn't change).